# Google Appscript - Scripting to copy existing folders with files by creating new folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to use a script that creates a Parent folder and subfolders and also copies any templates within a drive

The sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zc_ZWGXHcM5qM4uPvVcchPWObQLDJysxbL0x2j4Kr6E/copy

I got this from https://www.techupover.com/create-google-drive-folder-structure-files/

I am trying to change this script to copy an existing folder with files to the newly created folder. OR if possible change this script to copy multiple files within the newly created folders (This one restricts it to copy only 1 file). Could someone guide me here as I am new to this.

```js
const CUSTOM_MENU_NAME = 'Neat Features'; // the name of the new menu in your google sheet
const CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM = 'Generate Folders Now'; // the menu item you'll click to run the script
const DATA_TAB_NAME = 'folder_data'; // name for the sheet tab that contains the folder info that will be created/processed
const LOG_TAB_NAME = 'log'; // name of the sheet tab that will store the log messages from this script
const DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'; // date format to use for the log entries. Probably dont change this unless you really really want to.

/**
 * 
 * DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING UNDER THIS LINE
 * 
 * ONLY CHANGE THINGS IN THE CONFIG.GS FILE
 * 
 */

/**
 * When the spreadsheet is open, add a custom menu
 */
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var customMenuItems = [
    {name: CUSTOM_MENU_ITEM, functionName: 'processGoogleSheetData_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu(CUSTOM_MENU_NAME, customMenuItems);
}

/**
* Bulk create Google Folders from data within a Google Sheet.
* This is the function to call from the custom menu item.
* Others are referenced by this one.
*/
function processGoogleSheetData_() {
  
  // get current spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Log starting of the script
  logEventToGoogleSheet('Script has started');

  // display Toast notification
  ss.toast('Starting!!!', 'Yep, we are starting...now.');
  
  // get TimeZone
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  
  // get Data sheet
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(DATA_TAB_NAME);
  
  // get all data as a 2-D array
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // create a name:value pair array to send the data to the next Function
  var spreadsheetData = {ss:ss, timeZone:timeZone, dataSheet:dataSheet, data:data};
  
  // run Function to create Google Folders
  var doCreateFolders = createFolders(spreadsheetData);
  
  // check success status
  if (doCreateFolders) {
    // display Toast notification
    ss.toast('Script complete', 'Finished');
  }
  else {
    // script completed with error
    // display Toast notification
    ss.toast('Got some errors. Check the logs', 'Finished');
  }
  
  // Log starting of the script
  logEventToGoogleSheet('Script finished');
  
  
}


/**
* Loop through each row and create folders, set permissions
*/
function createFolders(spreadsheetData) {
  
  // extract data from name:value pair array
  var ss = spreadsheetData['ss'];
  var timeZone = spreadsheetData['timeZone'];
  var dataSheet = spreadsheetData['dataSheet']; 
  var data = spreadsheetData['data'];

  // get last row number so we know when to end the loop
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();

  var folderIdMap = new Object();

  // start of loop to go through each row iteratively
  for (var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
    
    // extract values from row of data for easier reference below
    var rootFolderId = data[i][0];
    var templateDocId = data[i][1]
    var newFolderName = data[i][2];
    var parentFolderName = data[i][3];
    var folderId = data[i][4];
    var permissionEmailViewer = data[i][5];
    var permissionEmailEditor = data[i][6];
    
    // only perform this row if the folder ID is blank
    if(folderId == '') {

      // if the sheet doesn't have a specified parent folder name, then it goes in the root.
      // if the parent folder name is supplied then it had to have been created by this script, 
      // so get it from script properties (where the ID is saved during an earlier loop)
      if(parentFolderName == '') {
        destinationFolderId = rootFolderId;
        
      } else {
        
        var thisMapKey = createMapString(rootFolderId + '___' + parentFolderName);
        var destinationFolderId = folderIdMap[thisMapKey];
        
      }
      
      // display Toast notification
      ss.toast(newFolderName, 'Creating New Folder');

      // run Function to create Google Folder and return its URL/ID
      var folderDetails = createFolder(newFolderName, destinationFolderId);

      // check new Folder created successfully
      if (folderDetails) {

        // extract Url/Id for easier reference later
        var newFolderUrl = folderDetails['newFolderUrl'];
        var newFolderId = folderDetails['newFolderId'];

        //push the key/folder id to the array map so we can use it later in the loop
        var thisMapKey = createMapString(destinationFolderId + '___' + newFolderName);
        folderIdMap[thisMapKey] = newFolderId;

        // copy the template doc into the new directory (if specified)
        if(templateDocId != '') {
          makeCopy(templateDocId, newFolderId, newFolderName + ' Template Document');
        } 
                
        // set the Folder ID value in the google sheet, inserting it as a link
        var newFolderLink = '=HYPERLINK("' + newFolderUrl + '","' + newFolderName + '")';
        dataSheet.getRange(i+1, 5).setFormula(newFolderLink);
        
        // check if Viewer Permissions need adding - if there are emails in the column for this row
        if (permissionEmailViewer != '') { 
          
          // run Function to add Folder permissions
          var currentRow = i+1;
          var addPermissionsFlag = addPermissions('VIEWER', timeZone, dataSheet, permissionEmailViewer,
                                                  newFolderId, currentRow, 8);
          
          // if problem adding Permissions return for status message
          if (addPermissionsFlag == false) {
            // display Toast notification and return false flag
            ss.toast('Error when adding Viewer Permissions to: ' + newFolderName, 'Error');
            return false;
          }
          
        }

        // check if Editor Permissions need adding - if there are emails in the column for this row
        if (permissionEmailEditor != '') { 
          
          // run Function to add Folder permissions
          var currentRow = i+1;
          var addPermissionsFlag = addPermissions('EDITOR', timeZone, dataSheet, permissionEmailEditor,
                                                  newFolderId, currentRow, 9);
          
          // if problem adding Permissions return for status message
          if (addPermissionsFlag == false) {
            // display Toast notification and return false flag
            ss.toast('Error when adding EDITOR Permissions to: ' + newFolderName, 'Error');
            return false;
          }
          
        }
        
        // write all pending updates to the google sheet using flush() method
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        
      } else {
        // write error into 'Permission Added?' cell and return false value
        dataSheet.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue('Error creating folder. Please see Logs');
        // new Folder not created successfully
        return false;
      }

    } else {

      ss.toast('Skipping Row - Folder ID already set', 'Moving onto the next row to process');

    }
    
  } // end of loop to go through each row in turn **********************************
  
  // completed successfully
  return true;
  
  
}

function makeCopy(sourceDocumentId, destinationFolderId, destinationFileName) {

  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  
  return DriveApp.getFileById(sourceDocumentId).makeCopy(destinationFileName,destinationFolder);

}


/**
 * Function to create new Google Drive Folder and return details (url, id)
*/

function createFolder(folderName, destinationFolderId) {
  
  try {
    // get destination Folder
    var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  }
  catch(e) {
    logEventToGoogleSheet('Error getting destination folder: ' + e + e.stack);
    var destinationFolder = false;
  }
  
  
  // proceed if successfully got destination folder
  if (destinationFolder) {
    var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    
    try {
      // create new Folder in destination
      var newFolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(folderName);
      // get new Drive Folder Url/Id and return to Parent Function
      var newFolderUrl = newFolder.getUrl();
      var newFolderId = newFolder.getId();
      var folderDetails = {newFolderUrl:newFolderUrl, newFolderId:newFolderId};
      
      return folderDetails;
    }
    catch(e) {
      logEventToGoogleSheet('Error creating new Folder: ' + e + e.stack);
      return false;
    }
  }
  else {
    // return false as unable to get destination folder
    return false;
  }
}


/**
 * Function to add permissions to each Folder using the provided email address(es).
 * 
 * role var can be either VIEWER or EDITOR
*/

function addPermissions(role, timeZone, dataSheet, permissionEmail, newFolderId, currentRow, permAddedCol) {
  
  // split up email address array to be able to loop through them separately
  var emailAddresses = permissionEmail.split(',');
  logEventToGoogleSheet(role + ' emailAddress array is: ' + emailAddresses);
  
  // get length of array for loop
  var emailAddressesLength = emailAddresses.length;
  
  
  try {
    // get Google Drive Folder
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
  }
  catch(e) {
    logEventToGoogleSheet('Error getting destination folder: ' + e + e.stack);
    var newFolder = false;
  }
  
  
  // proceed if successfully got destination folder
  if (newFolder) {
    
    // loop through each email address and add as 'Editor' *******************
    for (var i=0; i<emailAddressesLength; i++) {
      
      var emailAddress = emailAddresses[i].trim();
      logEventToGoogleSheet(role + ' emailAddress for adding permission is: ' + emailAddress);
      
      try {
        
        if(role == 'VIEWER') {

          logEventToGoogleSheet('Adding ' + emailAddress + ' as ' + role);
          newFolder.addViewer(emailAddress);
          var success = true;

        } 

        if(role == 'EDITOR') {

          logEventToGoogleSheet('Adding ' + emailAddress + ' as ' + role);
          newFolder.addEditor(emailAddress);
          var success = true;

        }
        // add 'Edit' permission using email address

        if (success) {
          // write timestamp into 'Permission Added?' cell
          var date = new Date;
          var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, DATE_FORMAT);
          dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue(timeStamp);
        }
        else {
          // write error into 'Permission Added?' cell and return false value
          dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue('Error adding ' + role + ' permission. Please see Logs');
          return false;
        }
        
      }
      catch(e) {
        logEventToGoogleSheet('Error adding ' + role + ' permission: ' + e + e.stack);
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  else {
    // write error into cell and return false value
    dataSheet.getRange(currentRow, permAddedCol).setValue('Error getting folder. Please see Logs');
    // return false as unable to get Google Drive Folder
    return false;
  }
  
  
  // return true as all permissions added successfully
  return true;
  
  
}


/** 
* Write log message to Google Sheet
*/

function logEventToGoogleSheet(text_to_log) {
  
  // get the user running the script
  var activeUserEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  
  // get the relevant spreadsheet to output log details
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var googleSheet = ss.getSheetByName(LOG_TAB_NAME);
  
  // create and format a timestamp
  var now = new Date();
  var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var niceDateTime = Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, DATE_FORMAT);
  
  // create array of data for pasting into log sheet
  var logData = [niceDateTime, activeUserEmail, text_to_log];
  
  // append details into next row of log sheet
  googleSheet.appendRow(logData);
  
}

/**
 * Create a string that can easily be used as an object/array key for reference
 * during the create folder loop. (Helps with identifying the parent folder dynamically)
 */
function createMapString(input_string) {

  return input_string.replace(/\W/g, '');

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts to find a solution on similar questions on this site as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I tried changing the script to something similar to what 'Yuri Khristich' suggested. But I then get the error that 'driveApp.getFolderbyID is not a function. The script runs fine without the edits = creates Parent Folder,  sub folder and copies one template and gives the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I figured out the solution. You need to make these three modifications:

1. Column B should contain **Folder IDs** (these folder contain files you want to copy) instead of **Google Document IDs**.

[image]

2. In line 136 you have to change the variable name `templateDocId` to `templateFolderId` this way:

```
var templateFolderId = data[i][1]
```

3. After the line 152 the code should look like this:

```
// copy the template doc into the new directory (if specified)
// if(templateDocId != '') {
//   makeCopy(templateDocId, newFolderId, newFolderName + ' Template Document');
// }

if (templateFolderId != '') copy_files(newFolderId);

function copy_files(newFolderId) {
  var src_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(templateFolderId);
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
  var files = src_folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) files.next().makeCopy(dest_folder);
}
```

After that the script will copy all the files from template folders into the new created folders (like 'Team A1', 'Team A2', etc).

The sheet with the changed script is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dw2aBgaw1u1n44QmGEeBoXtTCdKVZMFgCL927of56Lw/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function start() {
  var sourceFolder = 'source';
  var targetFolder = 'target';

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files = source.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: @ pranoy pugalia .... Thank you very much for sharing such a wonderful solution. The script shared by you copies entire content of one folder to another in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this modification after the line 136:

```
// copy the template doc into the new directory (if specified)
// if(templateDocId != '') {
//   makeCopy(templateDocId, newFolderId, newFolderName + ' Template Document');
// } 

copy_files(folderId, newFolderId);

function copy_files(folderId, newFolderId) {
  var src_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
  var files = src_folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) files.next().makeCopy(dest_folder);
}
```

A haven't tried it. It's just a guess.

Comment: Thank you! The code runs without errors but when I run the script on sheets I get this pop up: TypeError: Drive.getFolderById is not a function

Comment: My bad ) it should be `DriveApp` of course. Not `Drive`

Comment: I tried that but did not work - gave the same error.

Comment: Have you turned on 'Drive API' service in Script Editor? https://imgur.com/08v9rel.png

Comment: Yes, found that solution and enabled it. did not work :(

Comment: The error doesn't make sense, `getFolderById()` is a function. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid Only thing I can think you have no access to this folder. Try to make a test folders and files and try the script on them.

Comment: I just tried the function on my test folders and it works fine, all the files were copied from the source folder to the destination folder: https://imgur.com/P46cpOD.png

Comment: Trying again will keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.Details
 this is the error that I am getting now.

Comment: I changed the folder to something which is in my drive, but it still gives me the same error Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.

Comment: Alas... I have no idea what the 'unexpected' error could be out there. Sorry. I give up. (

Comment: Appreciate your time man. Thanks!